# Can I do branching/decisions with knockout.js

Tags: knockout.js

I had some old code i wanted to see if I could do with knockout.js.

```
    var secs = 960 + Math.floor(data.length / 6) * 1060 + 10;
    $("#metro-scrollbar").css("width", secs.toString() + 'px');
    var group_count = 0;
    section = ""
    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if (i % 6 == 0)
            section += "<section class=\"" + (data.length - i <= 6 ? "last" : "") + "\"><h2 class=\"section-title\">Group " + ++group_count  + "</h2>";

        section += "<a href=\"/TheoryTests/Test/" + data[i].Id + "/" + data[i].Title.replace(/ /g,'-') + "\">";
        section += "<div class=\"metro-tile double" + (i % 3 == 2 ? " last" : "") + "\"><div class=\"a1x2\"></div><div class=\"live-tile metrogreen\">";

        section += "<span class=\"tile-title\">" + data[i].Title + "</span>";
        section += "<div class=\"dark\"><div class=\"TheoryTestTile\"><p>Helo</p></div></div>";

        section += "</div></div></a>";
        if (i % 6 == 5)
          section += "</section>";
    }
```

The javascript generated a set of sections with some nested divs. Every 6 div it created a new section. I understand how i can databind with knockout.js

data-bind="foreach: test, visible: tests().length > 0"  but how can i do the decision making if(i%6 == 0)

UPDATE

```
<div id="metro-grid">
    <div id="metro-scrollbar" data-bind="foreach: tests, visible: tests().length > 0">
        <!-- ko if: $index() % 6 == 0 -->
        <section data-bind ="css: { 'last' : $parent.isLastSection($index)}," >
        <!-- /ko -->
            <div class="metro-tile double " data-bind ="css: { 'last' : $parent.isLastTile($index)}">
            <div class="a1x2"></div><div class="live-tile metrogreen">
                <div ></div>
             </div>
                </div>
        <!-- ko if: $index() % 6 == 0 -->
        </section>
        <!-- /ko -->

    </div>
</div>
```

the problem with above is that I still wanna generate the divs within the section . tests is a list of 12 elements. I wanna create a new section each 6th element.

UPDATE 2

```
function TaskListViewModel() {
    // Data
    var self = this;
    self.tests = ko.observableArray([]);
    this.sections = [];

    self.isLastTile = function (i) {
           return i() % 3 == 2;
    };
    self.isLastSection = function (i) {

        return i() >= Math.floor(self.tests().length / 6);
    };

    this.createSections = ko.computed(function () {
        var tests = self.tests();
        current = [];
        sections.push(current);
        for (var i = 0; i < tests.length; i++) {
            current.push(tests[i]);
            if (((i+1) % 6) == 0) {
                current = [];
                sections.push(current);
            }
        }
    });


    $.getJSON(url, function (allData) {
        var mappedTasks = $.map(allData, function (item) { return new Task(item) });
        self.tests(mappedTasks);
        //var secs1 = self.tests().length / 6 * 960 + 960 + 10;
        var secs = 960 + Math.floor(self.tests().length / 6) * 1060 + 10;
        $("#metro-scrollbar").css("width", secs.toString() + 'px');

    });

}
ko.applyBindings(new TaskListViewModel());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you add 2 ko.observables to your viewModel. The first being a 'sections' array, the second being a ko.computed in which every time tests is updated 'sections' is repopulated and then you loop over 'sections' with your binding.

Here's an example fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Zholen/q57RX/

```
var vm = function() {
  var self = this;
  this.tests = ko.observableArray([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,
                                 10,11,12,13,14,15,16]);
  this.sections = [];

  this.createSections = ko.computed(function(){
    var tests = self.tests();
    console.log(tests.length);
    for(var i = 0; i < tests.length; i++)
    {
        if(i%6 == 0)
            self.sections.push([]);
        self.sections[self.sections.length - 1].push(tests[i]);
    }
  });
};

<div>
    <div data-bind="foreach: sections">
        <section data-bind="foreach: $data">
            <div data-bind="text:$data">
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
</div>​
```

Comment: I just completed doing that when you answers. Guess thats the only way. ko.computed() means that it will be created each time createSections() is used ?

Comment: ko.computed will be called anytime ANY ko.observable that is used within the function changes. Note how in the fiddle I didn't actually call createSections() anywhere, thats because as soon as I set the value to 'tests' createSections was called for me by KO.

Comment: Ahh, didnt notice that. I did the binding foreach: createdSections and had a return sections inside the createdSections. I will use your approach instead

Comment: I got it to work, but do note taht every time createsections is called you add to the list. so if using ajax to get the data, there will be a empty section from the initiation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$index` object inside of `foreach` context:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: items">
    <span data-bind="visible: $index() % 6 == 0"></span>
</div>
```

Read more about `foreach` binding: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html

EDIT:
To avoid rendering:

```
  <div data-bind="foreach: items">
        <!-- ko if: $index() % 6 == 0-->
            <span data-bind="text: $data"></span>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </div>
```

Comment: My problem is that the sections should not just be hidden, they need to be not generated.

Comment: I could calculate how many sections there are and do two loops. but how do I do a for n loop where n is the number of sections.

Answer (score 0):

Knockout.js has an "if" binding: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/if-binding.html

Comment: Doesn't really cover the OP's question, which was how to conditionally display something based on ordinal position.

Comment: I added some more information. My problem right now is that the divs within my groupings are not generated.

Comment: Can you add you viewmodel to the question?